# rules scheduler performance

Tags: 6, rules

I use drupal 6 with rules. I have more than 200 scheduled tasks (updating node's field)waiting to be executed at one time. Do I need to worry about server crash or is there some kind of queue implemented in scheduler? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need the *Ultimate Cron module*. It is an advanced system for managing scheduled tasks. You can set rules and custom schedules for every single task. Can be found here:

https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron